# A Question about Random Variables and Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

In *Probability Essentials*, chapter 5.

After the definition of the expectation of a real-valued random variable on a countable space is given:

[image: Definition 5.1, Probability Essentials]

It claims that the following inequalities hold:

[image]

However, I have no idea about how the first inequality comes.

Comment: I believe there should be absolute values present. It should say
$$\sum_{\omega} |X(\omega)|p_\omega \leq \sum_{|X(\omega)|<1}|X(\omega)|p_\omega+\sum_{|X(\omega)| \geq 1} |X(\omega)|p_\omega.$$
It's just splitting the sum into those terms for which $|X(\omega)| <1$ and those terms for which $|X(\omega)| \geq 1$.

Comment: @kccu I see, thank you.